# How to make MacOS recognize previously installed packages because `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include` are deleted?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, homebrew

I was trying to uninstall my node.js due to some issues while I was very tired.  The next thing I knew...I accidentally deleted 2 folders, `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`, in my Mac Mojave!

I reinstalled the OS.  To my surprise, all my personal files stayed and so do the files installed by `homebrew` and `npm`.  What I noticed is that the npm packages installed previously are available, but I need to re-link them following the commands suggested by the intermianl.  So far so good.

However, it might not be the case for mongodb.  When I ran `mongo` I got the error: `-bash: mongod: command not found`. My Question: How do I make my system recognize mongo?

Here is the reproduction of the steps:

```
$ brew install mongodb-community@4.0
Warning: mongodb/brew/mongodb-community 4.0.9 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 4.0.9, run `brew reinstall mongodb-community`

$ brew services start mongodb-community@4.0
Service `mongodb-community` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community` to restart.

$ brew services restart mongodb-community@4.0
Stopping `mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

$ mongo
-bash: mongo: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I've accidentally deleted /usr/local things in the past.  To get the brew stuff back in I used `brew reinstall $(brew list)`

Note: python@3: I had to `brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies python@3` before issuing the reinstallation command due to a permissions clash.